# Push from Server to Blackberry Playbook

Tags: apache-flex, blackberry, actionscript, blackberry-playbook

Is possible to make a "push", initiated by a server, to send data down to a Blackberry playbook application?

If so how is this best implemented in Flex/Actionscript? ie. How do we capture this on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a server that has push technology like BlazeDS, GraniteDS, LCDS, Wowza Server, FMS, etc.  Although BlazeDs and GraniteDS isn't 'true' push (it's long polling), it should be more than adequate for 99% of all projects, plus it's completely free to use.

On the Flex end, you only need to setup the consumer to point to the AMF channel (your server) for it to work:

```
<s:Consumer destination="MessagingDestination" message="onMessage(event)">
    <s:channelSet>
        <s:AMFChannel url="YourServerURL" />
    </s:channelSet>
</s:Consumer>
```

Comment: @Flextras, it does, but to be honest, there's not a lot of good examples out there...

Comment: There is also Red5 server as a Java-replacement for Adobe's FMS